# Surround current selection with double quotes

Tags: firefox-addon, escaping, selection, double-quotes

I am making a firefox extension and I am trying to capture the current selection in the context menu and it works alright. However I want the current selection to be enclosed in double quotes. Code snippet:

```
contentScript: 'self.on("context", function () {' +
             '  var text = \"'+'window.getSelection().toString()'+'\";' +
             '  if (text.length > 20)' +
             '    text = text.substr(0, 20) + "...";' +
             '  return "Search Google for " + text;' +
             '});'
```

The javascript is enclosed withing single quotes and I have tried to escape the double quotes like in the code fragment above but I get the following output in the context menu:

```
Search Google for window.selection(...
```

How do I escape the double quotes in the search string. I tried to add the double quotes in the returned string but in vain. I think its probably because the javascript code is itself a string here. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
var text = "\"" + window.getSelection().toString() + "\"";
```

You can check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhC6E/1/) to see it in action.

Your code would look like this:

```
contentScript: 'self.on("context", function () {' +
            ' var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
            ' if (text.length > 20) ' +
            '    text = text.substr(0, 20) + "...";' +
            ' text = "\"" + text + "\""; ' +
            ' return "Search Google for " + text;' +
            ' });'
```

Comment: i had a typo there (a missing + sign). Was that the problem?

Comment: see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhC6E/2/) with almost that exact code working

Comment: @Annihilator8080. were you able to accomplish what you wanted?